# Can we make closures less glorious and exposed?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, election, moderators

I believe that closing should be made less rewarding and less exposed -- make the list of users who voted to close less prominent, for starters. I'm not sure the `[Closed]` suffix in the title adds any value either; it seems to be there simply to hang the question up as an example more than anything. Most other sites (blogs, forums etc.) have no problem with simply writing something along the lines of "Comments are no longer accepted" at the bottom of the page.

Many members are no doubt aware of the exposure on some level, and make a habit of dishing out closures liberally for that reason -- effectively almost ensuring an all-alpha moderation team.

Or, if there's concern that making the closures less exposed also removes accountability, maybe we can consider other solutions. Either way, I want to bring attention to the fact that this is likely an issue.

No one doubts that the moderation on SO and SE is becoming increasingly stringent, although the question of whether this is a good thing or a bad thing is in debate.

My suspicion is that this isn't what the majority of users (both long-standing and recent) really want (see my discussion on P.SE [here](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5161/is-high-profile-user-attrition-a-sign-that-a-subjective-se-wont-work/5163#comment12833_5163), where particularly a lot of users have concerns about the moderation), but that we ended up with alpha-personality, overzealous, micromanaging moderators because of a sampling bias in the elections, and to a lesser extent, a base of overly trigger-happy users.

Closing questions earns users a lot of exposure, with the SE UI putting their names in huge linked letters in the familiar **Closed by ____**. As a result, much as the [US presidential and congressional candidate with the most advertising spending almost wins over 90% of the time](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&ved=0CFQQFjAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.opensecrets.org%2Fnews%2F2008%2F11%2Fmoney-wins-white-house-and.html&ei=DnbfUKWuIYKpiALl9IHAAw&usg=AFQjCNGkpBj2k-ANZijr4tF4U_X2OB912w&sig2=w5EO78vmfkIXD5SWps1T7A&bvm=bv.1355534169,d.cGE), with the members that dish out the most close votes being the most visible on the site, they end up earning the most votes.

It isn't helped by the fact that making meaningful suggestions on how a question might be improved is more time-consuming than clicking on the Close button and commenting "See the FAQ". For many people, especially those who like feeling powerful, [it's also less primally rewarding](http://www.richardronay.com/CBS/Research_files/Power,%20Testosterone,%20and%20Risk-Taking.pdf).

Although it may be too late because the culture has already been established (and reflected in updated versions of the FAQs), it may, over a long period of time, lead to a different -- and I'd argue more representative -- group of moderators. To me it's becoming increasingly clear that the moderation on SE (especially more conversational ones like Programmers) is about habitually stretching the interpretation of the FAQ to close/delete as often as possible, than about maintaining focused and good content.

Comment: The public list of users who close a question works both ways, in that it prevents trigger happiness as much as it potentially promotes it. When I am about to click the close link, my mind is on the accountability facet of having my name under the question, not some supposed "glory" I will attain due to it. YMMV.

Comment: @Asad That's how you and I think, but for a lot of people (the kinds of people who I argue end up more likely to become moderators or vigilantes), it's more about the fame/thrill/glory than the accountability.

Comment: "...but for a lot of people [...] it's more about the fame/thrill/glory than the accountability. " -- **Citation needed.**

Comment: @Charles Not exactly a scientific source, but this almost goes without saying, and plenty of similar statements worded slightly differently can be found everywhere: [The Alpha Male is a Risk Taker](http://manformation.blogspot.ca/2009/08/alpha-male-is-risk-taker.html). A Nobel Prize winning Jewish philosopher (whose name I'll look up later) made the observation that those in power tend to be in power because society tends to reward risk-takers even when most of the time they're making the wrong move, because the one time they do happen to be right, their gains are big.

Comment: @Charles Pretty funny how you're wearing a [bow tie](http://winterba.sh/the-abby).

Comment: @Charles Ah, [Daniel Kahneman](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c4LdtAJaZPA), psychologist, not philosopher. Basic idea is that irrational risk-taking is disproportionately rewarded even though it's wrong most of the time.

Comment: @Asad, I wear one because it's *awesome* looking with my gravatar.  :p

Comment: Why would anyone want to have to load the entire page to then find out it's closed? That's why it's appended in the title

Comment: @ReiMiyasaka That is interesting stuff I'm sure, but could you point to some evidence here on SE of close votes by thrill seekers? My problem with your argument is that it presumes knowledge of people's motives that none of us have.

Comment: @random Good point, but I'd say that [Closed] only benefits people who want to answer the question. For people who want to read the existing answers, the downvotes are more pertinent. For people who want to ask a question, it doesn't matter, because their question's already been asked, it'll be a duplicate.

Comment: I'll point out that there is no direct reward for closing questions, and any correlation between close votes and rep is probably because you *need* high rep to cast close votes and close voters are probably those who care the most about the site. And closing questions benefits the community as a whole by keeping questions on-topic and answerable.

Comment: @murgatroid99 I don't doubt that closing is beneficial, I'm doubting that making the closings so overtly *exposed* is beneficial, because it's an [expression of dominance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expressions_of_dominance). The `[Closed]` suffix, aside from having other (probably useful) effects, is public humiliation. For the same reason, it's also a reward to the kinds of people who want that kind of reward. Not everyone is altruistic, and even generally altruistic people are not always benevolent.

Comment: @ReiMiyasaka You're reading too much into this.

Comment: @Asad That's not constructive.

Comment: @ReiMiyasaka `The [Closed] suffix ... is public humiliation`: No, it is just an indication that the question is closed. To think of it as some sort of public shaming is to overinterpret it.

Comment: @Asad You're seriously going to deny that no one feels insulted when their question is closed for reasons they don't feel are just?

Comment: @Rei: of course some people feel insulted. I don't know that's a good reason to *lie* about a question being closed though; far more people *read* questions than ask them, and *as a reader* I would tend to feel more insulted if I repeatedly opened questions only to find them closed.

Comment: @ReiMiyasaka No, that would be silly. I'm just going to deny that people are deliberately closing questions in order to boost their own egos and insult/shame others. That is what this question is about, no? People do get upset when questions are closed/downvoted/deleted, but this isn't an indication that someone is actively trying to upset them. Most people don't take it personally and bounce back.

Comment: @Asad No, as I've made pretty clear, the boasting and shaming is only *part* of the question, and the real question is the actual effect it has on the frequency of closures.

Comment: @Shog9 Sorry, do what? I can't figure out what you're referring to.

Comment: For what it's worth: I've closed a fair number of questions, and I can't really say it's ever felt particularly rewarding or glorious. If you're lucky, the person asking comes back and asks a better question; usually, you get either no response, or overt hostility. You've gotta be one sick SoB to close questions for the *fun* of it. Bill's answer nails the problems with your proposal, IMHO: you're making a lot of assumptions and jumping to some strange conclusions with very little effort made to back them up.

Comment: @Shog9 See my links. I'm not citing much direct evidence because in psychology, direct evidence is fairly hard to come by -- hence why it's often considered an art despite being able to produce a lot of useful information. Again, you and I may not be interested in closing questions, but that doesn't speak for everyone, whereas general psychological observations on domination behavior do speak for a lot of the kinds of people that end up wielding power.

Comment: The first five paragraphs of this could be edited out as it just comes across as...  Well, ranting.

Comment: @JollyOldSaintNicholas The first 5 paragraphs present the problem I've perceived for which the following two paragraphs present a possible solution. If I had to choose anything that's just ranting, it's the last paragraph.

Comment: @ReiMiyasaka Just saying, it took me a bit to get through the first five paragraphs.  It makes one lose track of what you're really trying to get at.

Comment: @JollyOldSaintNicholas Point taken, I'll reorder the question.

Comment: @ReiMiyasaka Well, there's no point *now*.  Just saying, for the future.

Comment: As the one saying there is a problem you are expected to show evidence. Not skip that and just wait for people to bring up evidence of where you have no evidence. The onus is on the one making the claim, not those listening to it

Comment: @random My evidence is the patterns of behavior seen in humans in similar situations outside of SE. Presumably everyone here is human, just like every other subject of human psychology research. That's how psychology works; definitive evidence is hard to come by, so you work with what seems patterned, reasonable, and actionable. I was careful to use the word "suspicion" because what's more important is the fact that changing the presentation of closures is quite actionable. Otherwise, I would have suggested a more massive overhaul.

Comment: @ReiMiyasaka Right, but we're asking for evidence that a certain psychological aspect is in play here, not that it exists. We all know human beings tend to be competitive and seek power; that fact in itself isn't sufficient evidence of problems on a broad enough scale to warrant the changes you are suggesting.

Comment: Wait, there's suppose to be glory?!? Then where is mine, damnit? I want the glory I've earned. Want, want, want!

Comment: @dmckee You're not power mad, sorry.

Comment: @Asad I've provided several: [mob/lynching mentality](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SjyrvfZlIbQ#t=45s), [irrational risk-takers tending to win power regardless of aptitude](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c4LdtAJaZPA), and [testosterone-driven risk-taking](http://www.richardronay.com/CBS/Research_files/Power,%20Testosterone,%20and%20Risk-Taking.pdf) and the joy it brings in dishing out reward and punishment (voting) rather than in seeking gratitude (providing answers). I'm not saying that most people here are that way; I'm saying that the closure UI gives those people an advantage.

Comment: *"I've provided several"* No, just like Asad said, you provided evidence that such behaviors *exist*, not that they come into play here.

Comment: @dmckee I asked Shog9 to give me something that might show that it *is* happening here, or at least to invalidate it, but apparently it's a tedious query. Rationalism exists outside of empiricism, but they tend to agree nonetheless, and in this case, it's rational to presume that it's happening here, because *there's nothing to say that SE is exempt from common human behavior*. The cost of applying my suggestion is more or less proportionate to the rigor of my evidence, and again, if that weren't the case, I would have suggested a lot more.

Comment: Claiming that we're no different is all well and good, but you've created a wobbly tower of supposition that depends on the claim that people are getting "glory" for closing questions. I've cast a lot of close votes over the years, and I have never once been congratulated for it. I have, however, been repeatedly castigated and called names for my trouble. Garbage in, garbage out.

Comment: @dmckee It doesn't depend on "glory". That's absolutely not what I said. I've said this in my other comments, but that's only *one* aspect. The risk-taking is another motivation for certain people; so is the sheer exposure. Is there glory in political ads? Not usually, yet they're incredibly effective, because you get your name out.

Comment: Even if one granted your premise, wouldn't removing the '[closed]' suffix in the question title lead to *more* views of each closed question, and therefore *more* visibility for each of the close-voters?

Comment: @DavidRobinson [I also said](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160841/can-we-make-closures-less-glorious-and-exposed#comment466700_160844) that the idea of removing the "[closed]" suffix is debatable, and that my main suggestion is that the way the list of close-voters is displayed be changed. I'd much less advocate doing the former without doing the latter.

Comment: Looking back at this thread and the notoriously toxic, troll-ridden community that SE has become, all I can say is, "I told you so."

Answer (score 18):

> No one doubts that the moderation on SO and SE is becoming increasingly stringent, although though the question of whether this is a good thing or a bad thing is in debate.

If that's in debate, then that's the question we should be asking, not basing new rules on the assumption that it's a bad thing.

> My suspicion is that this isn't what the majority of users (both long-standing and recent) really want...

Based on what?  Citations please.

> ...with the members that dish out the most close votes being the most visible on the site, they end up earning the most votes.

Voting to close questions is one of the *least* effective ways to get attention.  It's pretty thankless.  *Answering* questions makes you much more visible.  Having a lot of helpful moderator flags and being an active editor are both far more likely to help you get elected as a moderator.  Closing questions won't even put you on most people's radar.

> For many people, especially those who like feeling powerful, it's also less primally rewarding.

I don't see any evidence that "feeling powerful" is a major reason to cast a close vote.  I spend a lot of time in the moderation queue, and lately quite a bit of time in the close vote review queue.  Most of the questions that are there really do have something wrong with them.

> To me it's becoming increasingly clear that the moderation on SE (especially more conversational ones like Programmers) is about habitually stretching the interpretation of the FAQ to close/delete as often as possible, than about maintaining focused and good content.

I think you need to try to understand that having quality standards is what makes Stack Exchange sites better than competing sites like Yahoo! Answers.  The communities have a say in what goes into the FAQ, they make the content, and they elect the moderators.  If there's a specific question that gets closed that shouldn't be, the community has the power to override even a moderator's decision and reopen it.

In short, I don't think any kind of perceived recognition is the primary reason for close voting, as the majority of the close votes I've seen are on questions that actually need to be closed.  Unless this changes dramatically, I don't see any reason to change what little recognition/blame people do get for voting to close.

Comment: Edited with citations. Again, I never questioned that the strong moderation is useful (and it's obviously why I participate here and not on Yahoo Answers), but I'm suggesting that it's *too* strong -- more than what most users want. You're polarizing what I'm saying.

Comment: @ReiMiyasaka I'm not polarizing what you're saying, I'm just illustrating that you're not supporting what you're saying.

Comment: @Rei: if that's true - if moderation is *too* strong - then that's the problem that needs to be addressed - sweeping it under the rug by obscuring the fact that questions get closed and the folks closing them doesn't solve anything.

Comment: Voting to close does give you recognition. It's there, right underneath the question, underlined, colored, `<h2>`'d. The community also doesn't have *much* of a say, because reopening requires 5 votes (I believe), and hardly 20 people will look at some of the more esoteric questions -- of which most questions on SE are fairly esoteric by nature of the field.

Comment: @ReiMiyasaka You can consider it recognition or you can consider it blame.  I honestly don't pay much attention to who closed a question unless I think it shouldn't have been closed.  Reopening requires the same number of votes as closing.  Once a closed question is edited, it gets bumped back to the Active list, and once one person votes to reopen, it goes into a reopen review queue.  There are opportunities for closed questions to get views.

Comment: @Shog9 I'm deliberately supposing that the moderation is too strong, because it's been suggested plenty of times in the past. If there is a method for which it might happen, then it's likely (but not necessary -- hence why I'm careful to use the word *suspect*) that both the method and effect exist -- and in a lack of good evidence to say that moderation is either too strong or too weak, I'm suggesting a simple way to ensure that it *isn't* too strong.

Comment: @BilltheLizard That's a nice way of dealing with closed questions, but it still doesn't have anything to do with the fact that the current presentation and application of the close feature might be encouraging people to do it more than they should.

Comment: @ReiMiyasaka So you propose that we make the close list smaller, and take away the `[closed]` suffix?

Comment: @Asad The former, yes, it's the least that can be done without losing anything useful from the site. The latter, as I suggested, I think is debatable. The `[Closed]` title does have some utility, so it'd have to be weighed against the possible negatives.

Comment: @Rei: you're neither clearly defining the problem nor demonstrating that your "solution" would solve anything - indeed, I strongly suspect it would remove accountability and *create* a problem even if one doesn't exist now! "Too strong" isn't actionable; are good questions being closed? Salvageable ones not improved? Borderline ones closed now where before they were fixed? Define the problem, demonstrate that it exists, *then* propose a solution to it.

Comment: @Shog9 As I suggested in [the P.SE case](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/5161/is-high-profile-user-attrition-a-sign-that-a-subjective-se-wont-work/5163#comment12833_5163), there's very little direct evidence of the problem, but there's also very little direct evidence that the problem doesn't exist. What *does* exist is observations on group behaviors, and tons of anecdotal cases of people upset about [the excessive closures](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions) and complaining about it on meta, especially on P.SE, but also increasingly on the other SE sites.

Comment: @Shog9 I think you're right that making closures less exposed may reduce transparency, and I've updated my question to acknowledge this. Nonetheless, I believe the issue is worth pursuing, even if the solution might be something else.

Comment: @Rei: people have been complaining about excessive closures since SO launched. The volume of complaints has not, thankfully, scaled linearly with the volume of closures.

Comment: @Shog9 That's possibly (probably) because [people are more afraid to ask questions to begin with](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/2727/are-we-scaring-off-new-users/2769#2769). (I do suggest in my answer there that closing is preferable to downvoting, but I didn't intend that to be saying too much about closing as it was to disagree with excessive downvotes -- which to my mind is even more of an issue, albeit without any good ways to mitigate.)

Answer (score 11):

> Closing questions earns users a lot of exposure, with the SE UI putting their names in huge linked letters in the familiar **Closed by ____**

In addition to what Bill said, closed questions have a tendency to get *deleted* - so you're effectively painting your name on a building scheduled for demolition. Not exactly a great way to mark your territory...

---

...I don't see any real indication that having cast a large number of close votes helps you get elected. Remember, voters can't easily determine how many close votes anyone has cast...

### Close votes cast prior to being elected as a moderator

#### Programmers

469
301
209
163
139
893

#### Stack Overflow

212
238
454
2726
6466
154
266
168
481
1619
668
363

---

> For many people, especially those who like feeling powerful, [it's also less primally rewarding](http://www.richardronay.com/CBS/Research_files/Power,%20Testosterone,%20and%20Risk-Taking.pdf)

Quoting from the abstract there:

> Power has been found to increase risk-taking (Anderson & Galinsky, 2006) but this
> effect appears to be moderated by individual differences in power motivation (Maner,
> Gailliot, Butz, & Peruche, 2007). Among individuals high in power motivation, the
> experience of power leads to more conservative decisions. As testosterone is associated
> with the pursuit of power and status (Dabbs & Dabbs, 2000), we reasoned that hightestosterone individuals primed with power might be similarly risk-avoidant. Conversely, we hypothesized that high-testosterone individuals primed with low power,
> would see risk-taking as a vehicle for pursuing potential gains to their status and
> resources.

...This appears to be entirely inapplicable. Closing questions involves neither significant risk nor offers any potential gain - you don't gain reputation on the site by closing, there are no badges for closing, *you cannot garner additional power by closing!*

There's a *small* potential risk of getting called out by someone for voting to close a question. Unlike other activities on Stack Exchange, charges of careless closing cannot readily be countered with a clear, visible history of valid closing, so getting called out for one bad closure in 1,000 offers no less potential for stress or humiliation than 1 in 10.

I'm even less clear on how testosterone levels figure into this, given the overwhelmingly male population of Stack Exchange.

Voting to close (or voting to do anything else) is undeniably *easier* than answering, editing, or leaving constructive comments. This makes it a good tool for those situations where trying to fix a question isn't really worth the effort. But answering, editing, and even leaving a comment are all more *rewarding*.

Comment: Yes, there is risk, as you pointed out yourself: "If you're lucky, the person asking comes back and asks a better question; usually, you get either no response, or overt hostility." More importantly, testosterone isn't just a male hormone, it's attributed to risk-taking, domination, anger and all those generally alpha male traits. And again, you and I may feel that answering and editing is more rewarding, but a lot of people do get a kick out of attacking things blindly. It's the same reason people love watching people screaming on TV debates.

Comment: Voting to close is not very much like watching TV.

Comment: Deletion has nothing to do with it. Not only are deletions not particularly common, if a question that you have your name on *because you disapproved of it* does get deleted, you're effectively [signing the bomb](http://stateofmind13.com/2012/06/09/missiles-from-israel-with-love-not-really-the-signature-is-lebanese/), not the demolished buildings.

Comment: @ReiMiyasaka You're mistaken. Deletions are *very* common.

Comment: @Shog9 Voting to close is like *shouting* on TV, or [cheering for the people shouting](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SjyrvfZlIbQ#t=45s). It's part of being a mob.

Comment: @simchona Okay, I honestly have no way of knowing how many deletions there are, but what does that change?

Comment: @ReiMiyasaka You're making the point that deletions have nothing to do with anything because they're not common. They are very common, and when a question is deleted the names of the people who closed it are no longer there. So this whole "mob effect", if any, is limited.

Comment: @simchona [I beg to differ](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions). Not only that, that's only a small portion of my argument. My main point is that, whether the bomb or the building exists after it's destroyed, many people are inclined to put their name on it.

Comment: @Rei: I *think* what you're getting at is the pile-on effect where one vote can lead to others adding their own without due consideration. This *can* be a problem - it's why *flags* aren't visible on posts anymore - but it's a problem that exists even when participants are completely anonymous (as with ordinary voting, and with flagging in the past).

Comment: @Shog9 I never thought about that, actually. I'm suggesting though that mob mentality can kick in even if you're not a follower of the mob (i.e. the people cheering), because there's a fair chance that you *will* have a mob following you.

Comment: I *really* have a hard time buying that, @Rei. For what it's worth, less than 20 people on Programmers regularly cast more than one close vote a day. [And that's a huge step up](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/1869/posse-nominations-for-aaronut).

Comment: @Shog9 Do we have statistics on how many close votes people were casting before they became moderators?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, @Rei.

Comment: @Shog9 One of my main points is that closing questions earns moderators a disproportionate amount of exposure, and people remember their names when the elections come up. It may not be definitive evidence to that end if moderators turn out to have been prolific close-voters, but if they aren't, I can move on content that I was wrong.

Comment: Also, the fact that there is a handful of people doing the majority of close votes speaks to my point that there's a certain personality type that has the tendency to want to close. If a large number of people were constantly closing questions, then it would indicate simply that the established community doesn't agree with most of the questions that new members ask -- and that, too, would suggest that my suspicion was wrong.

Comment: @Rei: on Programmers, getting *anyone* to close was like pulling teeth for a while there. I agree it's still not healthy (and this creates problems for re-opening things as well), but at least it's gotten *better*.

Comment: @Shog9 Better in the sense that it adheres better to the FAQ, in the sense that the content will draw in more searches, or in the sense that it serves the community's needs better?

Comment: Better in the sense that voting works better when more people are involved in it, @Rei. Oh - and I can't see any correlation between close votes cast and electability. See my edit.

Comment: @Shog9 Can you give those close-vote numbers as a percentage compared to the number of close votes made by other users of similar activity? Also, that's better in a theoretical sense, not in an actual outcome sense. The outcome of the recent changes to P.SE don't look that good to me, and I'm definitely not alone, as I showed in my link earlier.

Comment: Ultimately the number of close votes cast as a ratio of activity probably isn't a definitive indicator of whether or not drive-by closing earns you more popularity in the elections (or gives that perception) because legitimate closing is one of the primary activities of a moderator or moderator wannabe, but that definitely looks like significantly more closes than the average user -- and so at the very least, doesn't indicate that there's that *doesn't* happen.

Comment: Define "similar activity". None of those numbers are even in the top 10 for their respective sites. More interesting is simply the variance: you have folks getting elected with less than 200 close votes under their belts, and less than 500 isn't even uncommon on *Stack Overflow* where the all-time top close voter has cast 31,000 votes... You're fishing, @Rei.

Comment: @Shog9 How about, say, the number of closes made by other users within, +/- 5% of the reputation of users who became moderators. Heck, how about the number of closures made by the highest reputation users, compared to the number of closures made by people who became moderators?

Comment: @Shog9 I'm not fishing; for the third time, I'm looking for evidence *against* what I'm saying, because I don't expect this to be evidence *supporting* what I'm saying.

Comment: @ReiMiyasaka How about some evidence *for* what you are saying? I can see your argument being more compelling if you quoted meta posts referring to similar problems, or simply some linked to some examples of close vote abuse of the sort you are describing.

Comment: I gotta be honest, @Rei: the only way to do this justice would be to pull the number of close votes for every *candidate* in an election, along with their reputation at the time, flags at the time, etc. and then count the votes received by each and try to find some relationship. That's gonna be tedious, and I don't feel like doing it, particularly given that reputation will almost certainly have a bigger impact than anything else.

Comment: @Asad quoting myself: My evidence is the patterns of behavior seen in humans in similar situations outside of SE. Presumably everyone here is human, just like every other subject of human psychology research. That's how psychology works; definitive evidence is hard to come by, so you work with what seems patterned, reasonable, and actionable. I was careful to use the word "suspicion" because what's more important is the fact that changing the presentation of closures is quite actionable. Otherwise, I would have suggested a more massive overhaul.

Comment: Oh Shog you TEASE! :p

Answer (score 7):

A person could use up away a lazy afternoon listing the mistakes in this question.

'No one doubts?' Oh? Just how do you propose to support that proposition? I doubt. I imagine that a lot of other people doubt. There have been a few, discrete, changes in the site's policy which have pushed some questions over the line. That's not even slightly the same thing as some sort of monotonic, constant, trend.

In the vast majority of cases the people who close aren't moderators. Of all the people who vote to close, only a microscopic minority will ever even be nominated for diamond mod status. So the notion that people are getting political advertisement value out of having their names on the 'closed-by' list is laughable. We aren't up for election. We aren't fishing for votes. We're just 'taking out the trash' and 'boarding up the broken windows.'

And then you go on and on about the idea of a 'more representative group of mods.' 99% of the things that happen on the site happen due to the action of *non-moderators*. Ordinary users who have earned some rep. We could replace every single diamond mod tomorrow and it would have nearly no effect on question closure and deletion.

Not to mention your citation of a p.se meta discussion as supposed evidence of a groundswell of public opinion on stack overflow.

Are you sure your real initials aren't E and C?

Comment: Who the heck is EC? Shog9 [pointed out](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/160848/200548) that there's less than 20 people doing more than 1 close vote per day on P.SE. That to my mind isn't very representative of the community there; they may not be moderators, but they're a militia. Also, how much is "the vast majority"? As for more strict moderation, when moderators are boasting that the moderation is improving quality, it doesn't make sense to suggest that it hasn't gotten more strict.

Comment: What does p.se have to do with this? You wrote, " moderation on SO and SE". And if you don't know who E.C. is, you haven't been paying attention here.

Comment: @ReiMiyasaka [That](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160841/can-we-make-closures-less-glorious-and-exposed/160844#comment466726_160848) isn't a hard statistic. "Regularly" and "more than 1" might as well mean people who cast 2 votes instead of 1 every three or four days.

Comment: @Asad It's the best we have. It certainly doesn't support the idea that the majority of close votes are cast by a large number of people.

Comment: @Rosinante P.SE is SE, and even though it's one of most vigorously moderated, the changes to moderation are happening everywhere on P.SE. I don't need to know every SE celebrity to be paying attention to the problems here.

Comment: OK, I must ask: Why E and C? `:)`

Comment: @kiamlaluno Who is the most famous more or less troll in the last two years on meta, who likes to talk about 'EXP' and generally throw around wild notions?

Comment: Ooooh! I got it. `:)` Yes, his initials are EC. How could I forget about him?